# Impedir Macro usando MAC Address na rede

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, redes, macro

Uma planilha disponivel na rede, pode ser impedida de rodar uma macro se a maquina nao for "autorizada"?

Eu preciso bloquear determinados usuarios ou PC's, usando o endereço MAC por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você deseja identificar *o usuário*, há duas formas. Você pode usar a identificação do usuário registrado no próprio Excel simplesmente acessando a propriedade `Application.UserName`. Ou, você pode acessar o nome do usuário registrado na conta (login) do sistema operacional, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
Private Declare Function Get_User_Name Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim sName As String * 25

    Get_User_Name sName, 25
    GetUserName = Left(sName, InStr(sName, Chr(0)) - 1)
End Function
```

Se você deseja identifificar o *MAC Address* você pode usar o seguinte código (lembrando que *há um MAC Address para cada adaptador de rede no computador*, então esse código de exemplo retorna uma string com todos existentes separados por uma barra "/" - você pode alterá-lo pra retornar um vetor de strings se desejar):

```
Function GetMACAddr()
    Dim sComputer As String
    Dim oWMIService As Object
    Dim oAdapters As Object
    Dim oAdapter As Object
    Dim sRet As String

    sComputer = "."
    sRet = ""
    Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set oAdapters = oWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
    For Each oAdapter In oAdapters
        If Len(sRet) > 0 Then
            sRet = sRet + "/" + oAdapter.MACAddress
        Else
            sRet = oAdapter.MACAddress
        End If
    Next oAdapter

    GetMACAddr = sRet
End Function
```

Agora, se essas funções podem ser utilizadas para "bloquear" o acesso ou a execução da planilha, esse é outro problema. Há de se considerar algumas coisas importantes:

- O usuário escolhe se executa ou não o VBA no Excel ao abrir o arquivo. Assim, ele pode simplesmente impedir as macros de serem executadas e assim abrir a planilha de qualquer forma (tendo ao menos acesso ao conteúdo estático).
- Para alterar o comportamento da planilha com base no usuário e/ou *MAC Address*, você pode comparar as informações coletadas com uma tabela preconfigurada. A dificuldade ai vai ser a manutenção: quando você precisar adicionar um novo usuário/computador "autorizado", precisará garantir que todos os arquivos Excel pela rede sejam atualizados. Assim, ao invés de ter essa tabela fixa (*hard-coded*) dentro do próprio VBA, seria mais indicado tê-la em um arquivo texto acessível pela rede ou em um acesso disponível via Internet. Note, entretanto, que essa solução limita o uso da planilha se por acaso o computador do usuário estiver sem rede/Internet.
- Se você não proteger (com senha) o projeto VBA no arquivo Excel, um usuário mais experiente pode simplesmente abrir o código e alterá-lo. Para proteger o projeto, faça assim: dentro do editor do VBA, na árvore de arquivos do projeto, clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre a raíz do projeto; então, escolha "Propriedades do VBAProject" e adicione uma senha na aba "Proteção" (marcando também a opção "Bloquear projeto para exibição"):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Fontes originais dos códigos:
>
> - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/2252-get-windows-user-name.html
> - http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/388084-mac-address.html

Comment: Luiz, mais uma vez obrigado pela resposta tao bem elaborada. Quanto as observaçoes, a macro roda ao abrir a planilha, o usuario deve ter acesso a informaçoes e outros serão restritas ( a depender do usuario). Mas agradeço as orientaçoes.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Acontece que a macro *não é* executada automaticamente só porque foi condicionada ao evento de abertura da planilha. Toda vez que um usuário abre um arquivo com macros no Excel, *por segurança* o Excel questiona-o se a execução deve ser habilitada. Sugiro que vc teste o que acontece no seu sistema se o usuário simplesmente disser "não" pra essa pergunta inicial. :)

Comment: Entendi. Perfeito. (Y)